# towupper для национальных страниц кодировки

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Есть решения по типу `towupper` для национальных страниц кодировки? из типа `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t`).

Comment: Распишите поподробнее суть проблемы.

Comment: Делать заглавные буквы в разных национальных кодепейдж :) вот собственно и вся суть. Русская раскладка например, `towupper` ее не поддерживает.

Comment: И чем упомянутая `towupper` не устраивает?

Comment: Используйте для этого библиотеку [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/)

Comment: Жутко тяжелая и объемная библиотека, лучшая в своем роде для интернациализации чего либо. Спасибо за совет, (icu) не подойдет в данном случае.

Comment: "Поведение функции towupper зависит от категории LC_CTYPE текущей локали." https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=towupper&category=3&russian=0

Comment: Для winapi + mingw поведение LC_CTYPE не всегда очевидно, и в моем случае это просто не работает. Тогда уж лучше использовать `wctrans`, все остальное вокруг него построено. Но всеже разумнее уходить в чистое winapi.

Answer (score 2):

Семейство функций `CharUpper*` преобразует в верхний регистр, а `CharLower*` соответствено в нижний. Только это не для национальных кодовых таблиц, а для UNICODE. Если же вам нужно преобразовывать именно 8-битные символы в национальных кодировках, то это надо смотреть [National Language Support Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/national-language-support-functions)

Comment: Спасибо, пошел смотреть

Comment: @NewView, вы уверены, что вам именно кодовые таблицы нужны? А то у вас и LPWSTR и кодовые таблицы рядом. Это вещи не сочетающиеся - либо у вас 8-битные символы (т.е. кодовые таблицы), либо LPWSTR (т.е UNICODE).